# Android GridView filling order

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview with 2 columns. By default the the gridview is filled from left to right:

```
    |1|2|
    |3|4|
    |5|6|
```

But in my project i need it to be filled from top to bottom:

```
    |1|4|
    |2|5|
    |3|6|
```

Can anybody point me to the right direction to achieve this?

Comment: modify your adapter implementation to reorder based on your liking.  post your adapter class code for more help.

Comment: downvote on this is a bit confusing, I have the same problem and the question is worded perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [TwoWayGridView library](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview)

It lets you set the scrolling direction to horizontal and will align your items the way you want